# is it possible to store primitive properties as reference in a class?

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I'm running a simulation, which has a "timePerTick" integer variable. The user can set this variable to speed up or slow down the simulation.

The simulation itself is handled by a few classes, all of whom consume the timePerTick variable.

I'm having some trouble eloquently passing timePerTick to the classes, because if I pass an integer, it's passed as a value, not reference. Right now, I'm passing a function that returns a reference, which works, but it's not very pretty.

Is there some pattern I'm not aware of that can handle this?

Comment: You can always wrap your primitive with an object (like a 1-long array) and read/write `timePerTick[0]`, although it looks a little hacky.

Comment: One classic construction is to have a config that can be a class instance or an object, but it would be clearer if we had some simplified code

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason it needs to be passed by reference? If it's a user-supplied value, then it sounds like your functions aren't going to modify it, so it's not going to change.

If you really want the equivalence of passing it by reference, you could:

1. Pass the value to the classes each tick, like
   `myClass.onTick(timePerTick)`
2. Pass an object instead of a number.
   Objects in js are passed by reference. `myClass.onTick(globalState)`, where globalState is an object or the class containing your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an object, that has a timePerTick value. Objects are passed by reference.